# Randomness Test of Permuted Sequence

Tags: randomness, rc4, statistical-test

As we can generate a permuted sequence using KEY in KSA (Key Scheduling Algo) of RC4. Is there any way to check the randomness of the permuted sequence? 
Let say I created 100 different permuted sequences of range 256 {0,1,,2,...255} using 100 different keys. Now, I need to check either all 100 sequences have any relation with each other or they are random. 
The NIST statistical test suit is for bit-stream not for integers as far as I know. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

EDITED:
Let say I have a sequence: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
I use KSA to get the permuted version as: 
Let say key="pass123" it gives -> {3,7,2,9,1,4,6,10,8,5}
Let say another key="test123" gives -> {9,2,6,1,5,8,3,10,7,4}
and similarly another key gives another such sequence and so on...
Now I need to check either there are some relations between the generated seemingly random sequences or not. And also I need another algo which can generate such like random sequences.
Hopefully the query is much clear now!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What tests can I do to ensure my random number generator is working correctly?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/394/what-tests-can-i-do-to-ensure-my-random-number-generator-is-working-correctly)

Comment: But the original unpermuted sequences are actually {1,2,3 ... 250,000} no?

Comment: yeah! to be exactly it's {1,2,3,...,202500}